# Header plastic melts while desoldering

Tags: soldering, header

While I was trying to desolder a 6-pin header, the plastic holding the headers together melted. Now, that is fine, because I can pull out the individual pins that way, my question is, will the plastic melt onto the PCB, making it unusable because I won't be able to put new headers on?

Comment: If the plastic is melting, 1. your iron isn't hot enough, which leads to, 2. you're applying heat for too long, or 3. the headers are really cheap.

Comment: Its sonewhat counterintuitive that things are melting because it isn't hot enough...but Matt is right.  The higher heat helps solder melt before the heat spreads out down the pin

Comment: I am using a 50W soldering iron, i am applying the iron for 10 second tops, just to get the vacuum pump into position. I don't know about the headers because they were presoldered to the board. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I much prefer solder wick for desoldering - it's quicker, much more precise and doesn't involve trying to carefully lower 2 things onto the same board or the sudden shock when you press the button.

Comment: I second what LeoR says: (de)solder pumps are crap, wick sort-of works. You did not tell us what kind of header this is (photo??), but I generally try to separate the pins from the plastic first (destroying the header, but who cares), and then remove the pins one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the melted plastic won't stick to the PCB very strongly. A plastic or bamboo spudger will often remove it with a little pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Desoldering a 6-pin header with a soldering iron will be a destructive process, as you won't be able to heat all the pins at once.  Embrace the destructive nature and desolder it in a way that will protect your PCB.  Chop away what you can of the housing with nippers, dremel, dikes, whatever, and then remove one pin at a time with whatever method you choose.